# JPA select with two conditions

Tags: java, jpa

Help me please add two conditions for JPA.

I have the entity Subject *(some subject of a teacher – math, biology, programming and so one).*
Subject has a field: boolean deleted.

```java
@Entity
public class Subject {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private boolean deleted;
}
```

I have the second entity Teacher. It has `Set<Subject> subjects` – subjects which are attached to the teacher.

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "person_id")
public class Teacher extends Person {
    private boolean deleted;
    Set<Subject> linkedSubjects;
}
```

So I need to get list of subjects which are not yet attached to the teacher AND these subjects should not be deleted.

I can do this separately – get not attached or get not deleted. But how get both of them?

```java
public List<Subject> findSubjectNotInList(List<Subject> teacherSubjects) { // teacherSubjects - List subjects which still attached to a teacher
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Subject> query = cb.createQuery(Subject.class);
    Root<Subject> root = query.from(Subject.class);
 // Get all not attached:
 // query.select(root).where(root.in(teacherSubjects).not());           

 // Get all not deleted         
    query.select(root).where(cb.isFalse(root.get(Subject_.DELETED))); 

    List<Subject> subjects = em.createQuery(query).getResultList(); 
    return subjects;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Subject> query = cb.createQuery(Subject.class);
Root<Subject> root = query.from(Subject.class);
query
    .select(root)
    .where(cb.and(
        root.in(teacherSubjects).not(),
        cb.isFalse(root.get(Subject_.DELETED))
    ))
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is a mistake: Cannot resolve method where in Root. Is line 3 should be Root<Subject> root = query.from(Subject.class); ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to add the line. I will update the answer